# Setting tk.Frame width and height

Tags: python, tkinter

So I am creating a GUI and I am trying to make it so that everything fits on the screen appropriately.  I've drawn a rough sketch of what I want each part of the GUI to look like an it's size, so I know the rough dimensions of everything.

The first problem I am having however is setting up the Left half of the screen.

So the Left half consists of a Frame, which we'll call `MainFrame`, that consists of 2 Frames, which we'll call `LabelFrame` and `ButtonFrame`

- `MainFrame` needs to be 385 pixels wide, and 460 pixels tall.
- `LabelFrame` should be 375 pixels wide, and 115 pixels tall.
- `ButtonFrame` needs to be 375 pixels wide, and 330 pixels tall.

My issue is I have no idea how to set these sizes to the frames.

I've tried `self.config(width = num, height = num)` obviously replacing num with the appropriate values, but that didn't do anything.

I know with the window itself there is a `.geometry` method, but I haven't been able to find an equivalent for tk.Frame

Comment: Look over [`grid_propagate(0)`](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/grid-methods.html), if you specified `width` and `height`. Note, that your frames need to be under `grid` geometry manager in this case.

Comment: @CommonSense That kind of works.  The problem is that I need the objects within `ButtonFrame` and `LabelFrame` to stretch to fit the sizes of their respective Frames.  And `grid_propagate(0)` doesn't change those Frame's sizes when it's applied to `MainFrame`

Comment: @Skitzafreak I think you are looking for proper row and column weights to accomplish the resizing where you need it and not where you dont need it. Look into `columnconfigure()` and `rowconfigure()`

Comment: Why do you think your frames need to be precise widths based on pixels? It's almost always better to let tkinter decide on the width based on the contents. When you start adding more than just a couple of placeholder widgets, the UI will have a natural size that is probably better than whatever size you think it should be.

Comment: @BryanOakley the end result is I need an app that is fullscreen with no menu bar that isn't resizable.  So I have a fixed window size requirement going into this and I am trying to plan around where I want everything on this fixed window.

Comment: You have a fixed _outer_ window size. Why do the inner widgets have to have an exact size? Wouldn't proportional sizes be better? For example, either make the left 1/3 the width, or make it just wide enough to hold the buttons and widgets that are inside. You are almost always better off letting tkinter decide the size of frames either based on what's in them, or  based on a size relative to  their container.

Comment: Do you know for a fact that your program will always run on a screen with the exact same dimensions?

Comment: @BryanOakley Yes I know for a fact that the program I am creating will ALWAYS be running on an 800x480 tablet screen

Answer (score 14):

Use `grid_propagate(0)` or `pack_propagate(0)`, depenending on geometry manager in use. `0` is just `False`, that told tkinter to shut off geometry propagation.

By default, propagation is on, and a container grows/shrinks to be just big enough to hold its contents.

And I assume that your desired layout something like this:

```
try:
    import tkinter as tk
except ImportError:
    import Tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

MainFrame = tk.Frame(root, width=385, height=460, relief='raised', borderwidth=5)
LabelFrame = tk.Frame(MainFrame, width=375, height=115, relief='raised', borderwidth=5)
ButtonFrame = tk.Frame(MainFrame, width=375, height=330, relief='raised', borderwidth=5)

some_label = tk.Label(LabelFrame, text='Simple Text')
some_button = tk.Button(ButtonFrame, text='Quit', command=root.destroy)

for frame in [MainFrame, LabelFrame, ButtonFrame]:
    frame.pack(expand=True, fill='both')
    frame.pack_propagate(0)

for widget in [some_label, some_button]:
    widget.pack(expand=True, fill='x', anchor='s')

root.mainloop()
```

and with [`grid`](http://www.tkdocs.com/tutorial/grid.html) manager the difference only in a loop section (note `sticky` and `row/column configure`):

```
...
for frame in [MainFrame, LabelFrame, ButtonFrame]:
    # sticky='nswe' acts like fill='both'
    frame.grid(sticky='nswe')
    frame.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
    frame.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
    frame.grid_propagate(0)

for widget in [some_label, some_button]:
    # sticky='wse' acts like fill='x' + anchor='s'
    widget.grid(sticky='wse')

root.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
root.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
...
```

Comment: How would I change your code for grid instead of pack?  does `.grid()` also have expand and fill parameters?

Comment: `grid_propagate` is almost never the right answer. While technically it will get the job done, a UI designed with fixed widths is fundamentally a bad design.

Comment: @Skitzafreak, kind off. `grid` has a `sticky` option (`fill='x'` similar to `sticky='we'`). For `expand` behaviour you can set `columnconfigure` and `rowconfigure`. Take a look over section *Handling Resize* [here](http://www.tkdocs.com/tutorial/grid.html).

Comment: @Bryan Oakley, definitely! When 4k resolution will get to masses - someone will learn the lesson you are talking about.

Answer (score 4):

While I never recommend building a UI to a fixed pixel size, if that's what you're doing than the simplest solution is to use `place`. `place` gives you absolute control over the location and size of widgets, and will not cause frames to grow or shrink to fit their contents.

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("800x480")

mainframe = tk.Frame(root, background="bisque")
labelframe = tk.Frame(mainframe, background="pink")
buttonframe = tk.Frame(mainframe, background="yellow")

mainframe.place(x=0, y=0, anchor="nw", width=385, height=460)
labelframe.place(x=0, y=0, anchor="nw", width=375, height=115)
buttonframe.place(x=0, y=116, anchor="nw", width=375, height=330)

root.mainloop()
```

You will page a huge penalty if you ever need to run this on a device with a different resolution or different fonts because it will be a nightmare to rearrange everything. Even if you're targeting a fixed size outer window, I personally recommend using `grid` or `pack` on the inside and using relative sizes (eg: make the mainframe fill half the width and all of the height)

Comment: Another reason I am trying this is because when I tried to set up the window in a way where the UI elements would autosize, I could never get it to autosize correctly.  It always gave me a tiny window, or when I specified the screen size via `root.minsize()` I would only have my UI elements appear in a small corner of the screen.

Comment: @Skitzafreak: those are solvable problems, without having to resort to using `place`.

Comment: I'll make a new question with a better explanation of what it is I'm having a problem with.  I'll keep the info I got here in my back pocket though, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are looking for column and row weights using `columnconfigure()` and `rowconfigure()`

Try something like this.

```
import tkinter as tk


class MintApp(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs)
        self.root = parent
        self.root.columnconfigure(0, weight=0)
        self.root.rowconfigure(0, weight=0)        


        main_frame = tk.Frame(self.root, width=385, height=460, background="black")
        main_frame.columnconfigure(0, weight=0)
        main_frame.rowconfigure(0, weight=0)
        main_frame.grid(row=0, column=0)

        label_frame = tk.Frame(main_frame, width=375, height=115, background="blue")
        label_frame.grid(row=0, column=0)

        button_frame = tk.Frame(main_frame, width=375, height=330, background="green")
        button_frame.grid(row=1, column=0)



if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk() 
    MyApp = MintApp(root)

    tk.mainloop()
```

Comment: you can't have fixed height with this! proof me wrong

Comment: @AbdullahSaid The goal was not for fixed height. Just a way to fit everything on the screen dynamically. For fixed height you need something like `grid_propagate(0)`.