# Widget in a second frame in a main class does not appear

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I am trying to add a second frame inside my main class and put there a few widgets. I created a frame by using a method and assigned one of the widget to that frame but the problem is it does not appear.

I provided below piece of code with window configuration and 2x Labels which are at the main frame (Both appear correctly) and one in the new frame which appearing problem.

If you have some idea, please help me :)

```
import tkinter as tk

class MainApplication(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        # Adding a background picture
        self.background_img = tk.PhotoImage(file="in office.png")
        back_ground_img_label = tk.Label(self, image=self.background_img)
        back_ground_img_label.pack(fill="both", expand=True)

        # Adjusting the window
        width_of_window = 1012
        height_of_window = 604
        screen_width = self.winfo_screenwidth()
        screen_height = self.winfo_screenheight()
        x_coordinate = int((screen_width / 2) - (width_of_window / 2))
        y_coordinate = int((screen_height / 2) - (height_of_window / 2) - 30)
        self.geometry(
            f"{width_of_window}x{height_of_window}+{x_coordinate}+{y_coordinate}"
        )

        self.bet_frame()

        bet_value_label_bg = tk.Label(self)
        bet_value_label_bg.place(x=462, y=300)
        coin_button_1 = tk.Button(self.frame)
        coin_button_1.place(x=233, y=435)

    def bet_frame(self):
        self.frame = tk.Frame(width=1012, height=604)
        self.frame.pack()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    MainApplication().mainloop()
```

Comment: `def bet_frame` needs to be indented. I have changed it.

Comment: Yes thank you, in code sure it is indented, i have made a mistake there.

Comment: When entering code in the text just put it in ``` tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only thing you put in the self.frame is the coin_button_1, but as you place it at (233, 435) is is hidden below the main window self.

Personally I would not use place but rather either pack or even better grid to place the widgets on the screen (see [Setting Frame width and height](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44826267/setting-tk-frame-width-and-height))

So if you change `def bet_frame(self)` as follows it will be visible

```
...
        bet_value_label_bg = tk.Label(self, text='value')
        bet_value_label_bg.place(x=462, y=300)

    def bet_frame(self):
        self.frame = tk.Frame(master=self, width=1012, height=604)
        self.frame.pack()
        coin_button_1 = tk.Button(self.frame, text='coin button')
        coin_button_1.pack()
...
```

Note the bet_value_label_bg shows up in the middle of the picture and you may have to expand the main window to make the self.frame visible, depending on the size of the picture.

Comment: Ok i see, thank you Bruno, but what if i need a specific place for that button? pack method would not be enough.

Comment: You are correct that pack is rather limited. If placing of widgets becomes somewhat complicated use the grid method. See for documentation https://effbot.org/tkinterbook/grid.htm. Further if you ok with my answer place can you tick it as answered, so I get my kudos, thanks!

Comment: If you want to see an example on how to use pack and grid, see https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/231930/python-sound-visualizer