# tkinter adding widgets in label frame break label frame size

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I have a tkinter label frame which I have set the width and height. However when I try to add labels if break those sizes

**Code:**

```
    # ------------------------------
    # Players Tab
    # ------------------------------
    playerListBox = Listbox(players, width=30, height=26)
    playerListBox.grid(row=0,rowspan=2,column=0,padx=4,pady=10)

    # Player Details Frame
    playerDetailsLabelFrame = LabelFrame(players, text="Player Details", width=500, height=195)
    playerDetailsLabelFrame.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky='NW', padx=5, pady=5, ipadx=5, ipady=5)

    playerFirstNameLabel = Label(playerDetailsLabelFrame, text="FirstName:", font='Helvetica 8 bold')
    playerFirstNameLabel.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky='NW', padx=1, pady=1)
    playerFirstNameData = Label(playerDetailsLabelFrame, text="Alex", font='Helvetica 8')
    playerFirstNameData.grid(row=0, column=2, padx=1, pady=1)


    playerFirstNameLabel = Label(playerDetailsLabelFrame, text="Lastname:", font='Helvetica 8 bold')
    playerFirstNameLabel.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky='NW', padx=1, pady=1)
    playerFirstNameData = Label(playerDetailsLabelFrame, text="Abrines", font='Helvetica 8')
    playerFirstNameData.grid(row=1, column=2, padx=1, pady=1)
```

**Design:**

[image]

Comment: Try put `playerFirstNameData` into column 1? You have 2 Labels on same column and row.

Comment: @LV98 I have update the code but still doesnt keep the frame size

Comment: Does this help https://stackoverflow.com/a/44827380/12485722?

Comment: What makes you think the frame size wont change when you add labels? You probably want `grid_propagate(0)`. Frames resize automatically when widgets are applied. Regardless of defined width/height. You need to explicitly tell the frame to not resize. That said your code example is not testable on its own. Please add in the rest. (root, imports, mainloop, and so on)

Comment: Thank you that work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using `pack()` and `grid()` for any widget added to a frame you need to explicitly tell the frame to not resize. This is still true even if you have specifically specified a width and/or height. This is because unless otherwise told the frame will resize the second a widget is added.

For `grid()` use:

```
frame.grid_propagate(0)
```

For `pack()` use:

```
frame.pack_propagate(0)
```